# Running mocha test but Getting error: ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, mocha.js, test-reporting

I am using mocha testing framework to test Http rest-api. I want to generate test-report for all test case, but when I ran `mocha --reporter html > report.html`
**Getting following error**

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/reporters/html.js:263
  var div = document.createElement('div');
            ^
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at fragment (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/reporters/html.js:263:13)
    at new HTML (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/reporters/html.js:53:14)
    at Mocha.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:459:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:393:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

Answer (score 13):

The reporter named `html` is *only* to be used when running Mocha *in* a browser. Running Mocha from the command line won't work with it.

There is a reporter named `doc`, which outputs "html documentation" according to `mocha --reporters`. By the way, when you run `mocha --reporters` you won't see `html` listed as a reporter, for the reason I've given above.

Answer (score 10):

if you don't need to test it in a browser,
then you can use `jsdom-global`:

```
mocha -r jsdom-global/register
```

Comment: this somehow helped me a lot as otherwise, I don't have any mock for the DOM. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You should use a headless browser to avoid this problem. Try with [mocha-phantomjs](https://github.com/nathanboktae/mocha-phantomjs).

Comment: This didn't work for me because I'm testing a Node.JS app and Mocha-PhantomJS expects browser-based tests.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve a simpler version of this problem by conditionally defining `document`:

```
let document = (typeof document === "undefined") ? {} : document;
```

I expect you could use the same approach, but would need to set `document` to something that mocks `createElement`.

Comment: That's not viable. The OP would have to mock not only `createElement` but `getElementsByTagName`, `getElementById`, `devicePixeRatio`, `width`, `height`, `getContext`, `style`, `className`, `addEventListener`, `innerHTML`, and many many more. That's a **huge** task. The HTML reporter expects a full-fledged DOM environment.

Comment: Oh, I missed that the error is in mocha's code, not the code being tested.  That is a harder problem.  The principle might still work, I think there are libraries that do mock a (near-)complete DOM, but I'm not sure that counts as "the same approach".